# AngularJs httpprovider.interceptors responseError has the wrong status

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I have created a simple interceptor to redirect user to the login page is the server returns a 401 error. It's not working though as the status is being set as 404, so $location is never called.

```
.config( function myAppConfig( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider ) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise( '/login/authorize' );

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$location', function($location) {
        return {
            responseError: function(rejection) {
                console.log(rejection);
                switch (rejection.status) {
                    case 401:
                        $location.path('/login/refresh');
                }
            }
        };
    }]);
})
```

[image]

Comment: Have you solved this? In my case the rejection variable is not populated at all. My rejection object looks like this: {data: "", status: 0, headers: function, config: Object, statusText: ""}

Comment: No, I had to put this issue aside as I didn't get anywhere with it and needed to move on to other problems. When I get back to it and post any solution I find here.

Comment: :-) So did I. The error object was not populated whenever I sent a 401 from my nancyfx module, so I assumed in my angular code that status code 0 was 401.

Comment: I have the same problem: the server clearly returns a 403 status, but the httpInterceptor has a -1 status... And this is not the case for e.g. 500 statuses

Comment: Same for me, I get -1 status instead of 500.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is the case in your situation @mike, as you are actually getting an error code - just not the right one... But perhaps the following is related...

Regarding @zszep and his issue of a status of 0, I also was having this issue and I believe that it's likely due to the error responses originating from your server not having CORS headers present as discussed here - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3336

This was the case for me - just wanted to post it here in case it helped anyone.